# Make children of Div to be shown on top of another in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with code

```
.popupClass {
    width: 632px;
    height: 210px;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom:0;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
    <div class="popupClass">
         <div style="margin-left: 90px; width: 184px; height: 210px; position:relative; z-index:1"  id="mainMenuDiv" hidden>
             <img style="z-index:2;" id="menu" src="images/popup.png" width="184" height= "210" alt="menu_btn"/>
             <a href="categories.php" style="bottom:-80px;" >Categories</a>
             <ul>
                  <li><a href="categories.php" >Categories</a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.php" >About Us</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>

         <div style="margin-left: 190px; width: 184px;" id="shareDiv" hidden>
             <img id="menu" style="margin-left: 90px" class="clicker" src="images/popup.png" width="184" height= "210" alt="menu_btn"/>
         </div>

         <div id="dDiv" hidden>
             <img id="menu" style="margin-left: 90px" class="clicker" src="images/popup.png" width="184" height= "210" alt="menu_btn"/>
         </div>

     </div>
```

[image]
the problem, is i want to show the ul on top of the  Image is such that, i can't add it to div backgrond otherwise it will get croped at some places because of div settings. How can i make the ul  appear on top of img

Comment: Could u provide a fiddle?

Comment: You can make the image a background without cropping is that fine?

Comment: it's fairly easy using absolute position, give ul a higher z-index than the image and set parent to positin relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
<div style="margin-left: 90px; width: 184px; height: 210px; "  id="mainMenuDiv">
   <img style="position:absolute;z-index:1; top:80px" id="menu" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
   <ul style="position:absolute;z-index:2;">
      <li><a href="categories.php" >Categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php" >About Us</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I am not entirely sure what exactly you want to achieve, but if edits to markup are an option, I got slightly simplified version of your code, which does exactly what you asked - it places menu items inside menu wrapper ON TOP of your html image.
So here is the markup:

```
<div class="popupClass">
    <img id="menu" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="menu_btn" />
    <div id="menuWrapper">
        <a href="categories.php" class="link">Categories</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="categories.php">Categories</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="about.php">About Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is CSS:

```
#menu {
    width:184px;
    height:210px;
}
#menuWrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:30px;
}
.link {
    display:block;
}
```

Obviously CSS can be inlined, but not recommended. Whole effect achieved by wrapping up menu items in a div container and positioning it absolutely, which gives you an option of using top, left, right and bottom to move whole lot regarding its parent.
If this is what you need then cool, if not let me know so I can adjust the code.

Comment: i have tried this, the problem is ul is shown under the img, not on top of it

Comment: is it possible to show the ul on TOP of img? i want the behavior, it would be if i add background to div

Comment: Yes - adjust "top" property of img element. it can be negative ie. top:-25px; http://jsfiddle.net/pn41ymgv/1/

Comment: Sure, so let me clarify - do you need your menu appear inside of the pop up right?

Comment: sorry for late response - and see edits to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use position property like,

```
<img style="position:relative;z-index:1" id="menu" src="images/popup.png" .../>
<ul style="position:relative;z-index:2">
   <li><a href="categories.php" >Categories</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.php" >About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can use [position: relative/absolute/static/fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) according to your design

And if you want it in background then use `backgroud-image` for `ul` instead of using `img` separately

Comment: i have tried, it does work however the ul is shown below the img, how can i make it appear on top of img?

Comment: Use `position:absolute` for `ul`. Why you are using `img` if you want it in `background` then use `background-image`

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, you want to have something like this:

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <img style="position:absolute;z-index:1"/>
  <ul style="position:absolute;z-index:100">
    <li><a href="categories.php">Categories</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You could then set top/left/bottom/right position to the `ul`.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qyh6zuq/)

Hope this helps